# How is the audio or image transmitted by the email client when I send them?

Tags: email, networking, mime

When I send an email with attachment of audio, image or anything other than plain ASCII bytes, how does the email client treat these various types of files? I can think of 2 options:

- do nothing about the file content, just send them unchanged with the mail text, but mark them with MIME info.
- re-encode these file content with Base64 and send them as text just like the mail text, and also mark them with MIME info.

So, what actuall happens?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just like any other non-ascii attachment -- Base64 encoded!  Try sending or receiving an email with an audio attachment while using Wireshark, and you'll see this.

Comment: Why do we have to Base64 it? Isn't it sufficient to mark the type of the attachment and send it out unchanged? The TCP protocol doesn't care what bytes stream we send.

Comment: SMTP is a pretty primitive protocol that only supports a limited character set (a subset of ASCII, with some characters reserved as special characters, I believe).  Base64 is the way to 'escape' characters that can't normally be represented.

Comment: As for TCP "not caring," you are correct.  In that sense, TCP is very flexible, but all sorts of protocols higher up in the stack DO care about special characters (eg, the ampersand in HTML).